# Linq query summing dates in range

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, datetime

Trying to work out if there's a nice way of doing this, preferably in Linq rather than loops, which is what I've done for now.

I want the number of days my Product is active between two dates.

Product has many ProductHistories, ProductHistory has values for DateActive and DateInactive. DateInactive can be null, and often will be, to show that this history is ongoing. Histories won't overlap.

I want to sum the maximum of my startDate or the ProductHistory's DateActive, and subtract that total from the sum of the minimum of endDate or ProductHistory's DateInactive (endDate by default if DateInactive has no value).

Worked example:

Get active number of active days between 2011-01-01 (1st Jan) and 2011-02-01 (1st Feb)

Histories:

```
Active 2010-12-25 : Inactive 2011-01-05
Active 2011-01-15 : Inactive 2011-01-20
Active 2011-01-25 : Inactive null
```

This should total 16 days (4 + 5 + 7)

My best at the moment is the rather ugly:

```
    Dim a As Integer = (From h In histories
            Select If(h.ActiveDate > startDate, h.ActiveDate, startDate)).Sum(Function(d) d.Ticks) / TimeSpan.TicksPerDay

    Dim b As Integer = (From h In histories
            Select If(h.InactiveDate.HasValue AndAlso h.InactiveDate < endDate, h.InactiveDate, endDate)).Sum(Function(d) d.Value.Ticks) / TimeSpan.TicksPerDay

Return b - a
```

Any thoughts? (Either C# or VB are fine, I'll translate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? (assumes no overlapping histories)

```
var numDays = product
             .ProductHistories
             .Where(ph => ph.Active >= start && ph.Active < end)
             .Sum(ph => ph.Active
                          .Subtract(end > ph.Inactive ? ph.Inactive.Value : end)
                          .Duration() // because we are doing start - end
                          .Days);
```

1. Only consider histories that *start* within the date-range.
2. For each history, construct the timespan as the delta between the active-date and the *earlier* of the inactive-date and end-date.
3. Sum them up.

To improve this, I suggest:

1. Write an `IsBetween` extension that would let you write the where lambda  as `ph.Active.IsBetween(start, end)`.
2. Extract the sum lambda out into a different method, and write it more intuitively. There's the use of a "lifted" operator on `DateTime?` that many would find quite unintuitive.